# Java hibernate load only child's where insertTime is no less than x days

Tags: java, hibernate

I have web app for print user ads by specific filters. I use `Java` on back-end and `Hibernate` as persistence framework. `User` entity has `oneToMany` relations with Filter entity and filter has `manyToMany` relations with Ad entity. Ad class has insertTime property. My goal is load only ads where not oldest then specific time e.g week (7 days).

front-end get user method:

```
var res = $http.get($rootScope.url+"users/getUser/"+id);
```

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class GeUser {
   ...
   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user") 
   @OrderBy("id")
   private Set<Filter> filters = new HashSet<Filter>(0);
   ...
```

Filter:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="filters")
public class Filter {
   ...
   @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   private Set<Ad> ads; 
   ...
```

Ad:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ads")
public class Ad {
   ...
   private Date insertTime = new Date(); // > no less 7 days
   ...
```

Used DAO method for load user:

```
public GeUser getUser(int id){
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(GeUser.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id",id));
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<GeUser> results = criteria.list();
    if(results.size()<1)return null;
    return results.get(0);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Hibernate filters](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html) is the way to load from database as your conditions

In entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="filters")
public class Filter {
   ...
   @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   @FilterJoinTable(name="time", condition=":insertTime >= insertTime")
   private Set<Ad> ads; 
   ...
```

And when creating query;

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // this would default to now
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7).
session.enableFilter("time").setParameter("insertTime", calendar.getTime());
```

Also you want see examples on [here](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/hibernate-filter-and-filterjointable-annotation-example)